# Some subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let's consider $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and $C_2\times C_2 \times C_2$, $C_2$ - cyclic group of order 2. I can't show, that group $C_2\times C_2 \times C_2$ is not a subgroup of  $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$.I don't know how to begin to prove it :-)

Comment: what are the elements $A\in GL_2$ such that $A^2=I$?

Comment: Hint: ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{Q})/{\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ and there aren't many involutions in ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{Q}).$

Comment: Hint: any commuting diagonalizable matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: Can you explain about "any commuting diagonalizable matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable" ? :-)